# Calculate position of the camera after rotation around some deliberate point on mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, camera, rotation

I am trying to implement the current scenario:

1. on mouse down event on the mesh focus perspective camera on the point where a user clicked
2. allow a user to rotate the camera via orbitControls;
3. after rotation is completed on mouse up event change camera position and target in such fashion that it would seem that camera is still looking at the mesh at the same angle that it was before focusing and rotation.

So it would appear that a user rotated the camera around some point on the mesh and after rotation is able to look at it at from the same place it used to be before the focusing and rotation.

There is no problem with 1) and 2)
And I am quite confused about the 3)

Here I've added some pictures which illustrate main steps

[1) User clicks on some point on the mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gp3n.png)

[2) Camera focus is set on the point where the user clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnQfZ.png)

[3) User rotates the camera around the selected pivot point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ole0x.png)

[4) On mouse up camera should be placed in such fashion so in user's eyes selected point is brought back to the place where it was and the camera is looking from the same angle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMBdf.png)

The question is how to implement behavior illustrated in the 4th picture.

Important thing is that thought it seems that the camera is looking from the same position and to the same target the pyramid appears to be rotated around the point where the user clicked.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: What if to use [`.reset()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.reset) method?

Comment: @prisoner849 if it will return camera position to state before focusing it is not what I am trying to do. Camera should look at same point but position should be altered to reflect rotation changes that have been made. Nevertheless, thanks, will try.

Comment: @prisoner849 Unfortunately reset doesn't help. It resets to previously saved controls configuration or to the initial ones. But in my case, It seems that I have to recalculate the camera position and maybe target as well so for a user it would seem that after rotation mesh is put back. It may look like panning after rotation to a certain target with the camera moving along. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I got you correctly.
Find the difference between the initial target and the target point on an object, and on mouse up - shift your camera position with this value.

```js
var w = window.innerWidth,
  h = window.innerHeight;
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, w / h, 1, 1000);
camera.position.setScalar(5);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(w, h);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10));

var prismGeom = new THREE.ConeBufferGeometry(1, 2, 3);
prismGeom.translate(0, 1, 0);
var prismMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "red",
  wireframe: true
});
var prism = new THREE.Mesh(prismGeom, prismMat);
prism.position.set(-1, 0, -2);
scene.add(prism);

var centralMarker = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(0.125, 4, 2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "aqua"
}));
scene.add(centralMarker);

var pointMarker = new THREE.Mesh(centralMarker.geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "magenta"
}));
pointMarker.visible = false;
scene.add(pointMarker);


var oldTarget = scene.position;
var targeted = false;
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var intersects = [];

window.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown, false);
window.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp, false);

function onMouseDown(event) {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(prism);
  if (intersects.length > 0) {
    targeted = true;
    controls.target.copy(intersects[0].point);
    pointMarker.position.copy(intersects[0].point);
    pointMarker.visible = true;
    controls.update();
  }
}

function onMouseUp(event) {
  if (!targeted) return;
  let shift = new THREE.Vector3().copy(oldTarget).sub(controls.target);
  camera.position.add(shift);
  controls.target.copy(oldTarget);
  controls.update();
  targeted = false;
  pointMarker.visible = false;
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
})
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It is not quite what I am expecting (at least in my mind) though. These manipulations are the first part of the rotation around any point that I would like to implement.  This is an example of the behavior I would like to implement:  

[link](https://vimeo.com/346095538)  

and my approach was like this:  
to select a point on mesh -> focus + rotation -> put it back and during the process hide centering/putting back action from a user.  
I would appreciate any suggestions regarding the algorithm itself or implementation.  
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
var w = window.innerWidth,
  h = window.innerHeight;
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, w / h, 1, 1000);
camera.position.setScalar(5);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(w, h);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10));

var prismGeom = new THREE.ConeBufferGeometry(1, 2, 3);
prismGeom.translate(0, 1, 0);
var prismMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "red",
  wireframe: true
});
var prism = new THREE.Mesh(prismGeom, prismMat);
prism.position.set(-1, 0, -2);
scene.add(prism);

var centralMarker = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(0.125, 4, 2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "aqua"
}));
scene.add(centralMarker);

var pointMarker = new THREE.Mesh(centralMarker.geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "magenta"
}));
pointMarker.visible = false;
scene.add(pointMarker);


var oldTarget = scene.position;
var targeted = false;
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var intersects = [];

window.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown, false);
window.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp, false);

function onMouseDown(event) {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(prism);
  if (intersects.length > 0) {
    targeted = true;
    controls.target.copy(intersects[0].point);
    pointMarker.position.copy(intersects[0].point);
    pointMarker.visible = true;
    controls.update();
  }
}

function onMouseUp(event) {
  if (!targeted) return;
  let shift = new THREE.Vector3().copy(oldTarget).sub(controls.target);
  camera.position.add(shift);
  controls.target.copy(oldTarget);
  controls.update();
  targeted = false;
  pointMarker.visible = false;
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
})
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).